# Can't get a text value from mysql into json string

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get my database into a json string using the following code:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM database";
$result=mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$json[] = $row;
}

$json = json_encode($json);
```

It works fine for 3 columns (id and 2 VarChar) but for the last one, which is in the text format, it return null value.

Help, please?

Edit: The json output:

```
string(96) "[{"id":"1","name":"NAME 1","text":null},{"id":"2","name":"NAME 2","text":null}]"
```

Edit2: The var_dump($json):

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(6) "NAME 1" ["text"]=> string(4) "text" } [1]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(6) "NAME 2" ["text"]=> string(4) "text" } }
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($row)` show?

Comment: It shows the right json form, with the text. But why is the json_encode getting null value?

Comment: could you provide the json output in your question?

Comment: Edited the original post including the output

Comment: Can you add the `var_dump` to the question?

Comment: try the snippet i gave you .

Comment: Still getting null there...

Thanks for the help, btw!

Comment: Edited with the var_dump, Barmar!

Comment: Found my mistake, thanks everybody!!